# how to build single sql query for QSQLite for text search on table

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, search

im using QSQLite in Qt 4.8 and trying to do Full Text Search
im trying to find away to build query that preform text search using LIKE and %str%
or maybe other query.
i have table with N columns and i like to build query so if i search "foo"
it will give me as results all the rows that part or all of the strings in one of the row columns contains "foo".
what is the best way to do it in SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SQLite FTS3 and FTS4 Extensions](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)

Quoting documentation samples:

```
-- Example schema
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE mail USING fts3(subject, body);

-- Example table population
INSERT INTO mail(docid, subject, body) VALUES(1, 'software feedback', 'found it too slow');
INSERT INTO mail(docid, subject, body) VALUES(2, 'software feedback', 'no feedback');
INSERT INTO mail(docid, subject, body) VALUES(3, 'slow lunch order',  'was a software problem');

-- Example queries
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE mail    MATCH 'software';    -- Selects rows 1, 2 and 3
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE mail    MATCH 'slow';        -- Selects rows 1 and 3
```

Notice that this look for your pattern in all table columns!

Comment: thanks for replay i updated my question , im using Qt as my sdk